# Indexes and indexes entries limits in Google App Engine Datastore

Tags: database, google-app-engine, indexing, google-cloud-datastore

I'm having some problem in understanding how indexes work in GAE Datastore, in particular somthing really unclear to me are the limits related to indexes.
For what I understood one can create some custom indexes in the datastore-indexes.xml file and additionally the Datastore will generate some automatic indexes to match the user queries.
A first question is: the "Number of indexes" quota limit defined in the quotas page (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Datastore) is referred only to the custom indexes defined in datastore-indexes.xml, or it applies also to indexes automatically generated?

Another concept eluding me is the "index entry for a single query".
Assume I don't have multi-dimensional properties (i.e. not lists) and I have some entities of kind "KindA". Then I define two groups of entity properties:
 - Group1: properties with arbitray name and boolean value
 - Group2: properties with arbitray name and double value

In my world any KindA entity can have at most N properties of Group1 and N properties of Group2. For any property P an index table is created and each entity having that P set will add a row in the P index table (right?).  Thus initially any KindA entity will have 1 entry for each of the max. 2N properties (thus in total max 2N index entries per entity) right?
If this is correct than it follows that I can create an entity with a limited number of properties, however this is strange since I 've always read that an entity can have unlimited properties...(without taking in account the size limit).
However let assume now that my application allows users to query for KindA entities using an arbitrarly long sequence of AND filters on properties of Group1 (boolean one). Thus one can query something like:

```
find all entities in KindA where prop1=true AND prop2=true ... AND propM = true
```

This is a situation in which query only contains equalities and thus no custom indexes are required (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/indexes#Index_configuration).

But what if I want to order using properties of GroupB ?  In this case I need an index for any different query right (different in terms of combination of filtering properties names)?
In my developmnet server I tried without specifying any custom index and GAE generates them for me (however any time I restart previous generated indexes get removed). In this case how many index entries does a signle KindA entity have in a single query index? I say 1 because of what GAE docs says:

> The property may also be included in additional, custom indexes declared in your index configuration file (index.yaml). Provided that an entity has no list properties, it will have at most one entry in each such custom index (for non-ancestor indexes) or one for each of the entity's ancestors (for ancestor indexes)

Thus in theory if N is limited I'm safe with respect to the "Maximum number of index entries for an entity" (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/#Java_Quotas_and_limits) is it right?

But what about receiving over 200 different queries? does it leads GAE to automatically generate over 200 custom indexes (one for distinct query)? If yes, do these indexes automatically generate influence the Indexes number limit (which is 200) ?
If yes, then it follows that I can't let user do this (IMHO very basic) queries. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26751944/gae-datastore-index-limit/26752378#26752378

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first of all I was trying to understand your question which I find difficult to follow.

The 200 index limit only counts towards the indexes you (or are define for you automatically by the devappserver) define by using queries. This means that the indexes that will be created alone for your indexed properties are not counted towards this limit.

Your are correct in the 2N automatic indexes created for every indexed property.

You can have any number of properties indexed in any entity as long as you don't get over the 1MB limit per entity. But.. this really depends on the content of the properties stored.

For the indexes created for you on your indexed properties... you don't really have an actual limit rather than an increasing cost as your writes and storage per entity put will increase for each added property.

When using sort orders, you are limited to one sort order when using automatic indexes. More sort orders will require a composite index (your custom index). Thus if you are already using an equality filter you need anyway a custom index.

So, yes, on your example the devapp server will create a composite index for each query you will be executing. However you can reduce this indexes manually by deleting the ones not needed. The query planner can use query time to find your results by merging different indexes as explained here:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/indexselection

Yes, every index definition on your index.yaml will count towards the 200 limit.

I find out that you really don't use composite indexes too much when you know how gae apps can be programmed. You need to balance what users need to do and what not. And also balance between doing query side job, or just query all and filter by code (it really depends on how many max entities you can have in that particular kind).

However, if your trying to do some complex queries available to your users then maybe the datastore is not the choice.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Actually what I'm trying to do is to model weighted hashtag relationships. I have to tag KindA entities by max N tags and then retrieve only those entities matching a given set of tags (in AND) as queried by the user. Thus I thought that a way would be: at write time of any KindA entity define a property for each hashtag (boolean) and a property for each weight associated to the hashtags (double). This way I can get matching entities by filtering on hashtags existance and sort by weight. But according to what you said with this model I just can filter by hashtag, and no..

Comment: ... and not ordering by weights right? For now I could not find a better way to model this. Can you suggest something?
ps. I didn't create any custom index, GAE does automatically
ps2: are you shure that I can filter by N equalities in AND and sort by 1 property without making GAE to define composite indexes?

Comment: I tryed to launch 500 random queries in two times by 250 each. The datastore creates 500 indexes however it didn't throw any exception and executed all the queries... For what said above shouldn't it go beyond the 200 limit?

Comment: Gae do the custom idexes for u, but u can change that indexes or create newer ones by yourself. As stated in the documentation from "indexselection" you can use the zig-zap-merge-join algorith to lower your index count (and increasing the query execution time).

Comment: Filter by N equalities in AND and sort by 1 property will actually need a custom index. Sorry if I didn't explain it properly.

Comment: I don't know what you are doing with the 500 random queries, but some will not work if you exceed the 200 index limit.

Comment: I don't have enough data to help you...Try to define your problem on a gae project and execute it in the development environment and see what happens.

Comment: Yes is what I did. I simply executed over 500 queries in which each query made GAE to build a custom index (each tag defines a bool property named "_H"+tagname and a double property "_W"+tagname in the referred KindA entity. Any of the 500 queries searches for a combination of 5 random tags, thus GAE defines an index composed by 5 equalities and 5 sort orders on properties that are randomly generated. Thus it actually ends up with 500 indexes, however queries are succesfully executed and I don't know why, it should throw and exception

Comment: However your answer made me to reason about my dirty solution. I did not get how indexes work and now I understand how this solution is crazy.

Comment: At the end I never did a project using more than 30 indexes from the 200 allowed. It really depends on how you organize your data and what queries are your users allowed to do. Don't know why it let you do 500 custom indexes in the devserver. Maybe you can ask for that in https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/.